# Whitelabel Error involving href and Spring MVC

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I keep getting a whitelabel error with Spring MVC.  I get the following error in my terminal in eclipse.

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The reference to entity "mt" must end with the ';' delimiter.
```

The anchor tag href address is the following

```
<a href="https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/digital-blasphemy-3d-wallpaper/id836103948?ls=1&mt=8">
```

I cannot figure out why its throwing that error and its bloody annoying.  I've tried searching different topics to see if others had the same issue and haven't had any luck. I'm sure it is something easy and I'm just overlooking something but I'm currently at a loss.  Any help figuring this out would be appreciated.

Comment: In **href** , try adding `amp;` before `mt` such as `ls=1&amp;mt=8`

Comment: That worked. Would you mind putting that as an answer and I'll mark it correct.  Thank you.  I figured it was something I was missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In href try adding `amp;` before `mt` such as `ls=1&amp;mt=8`

It might be that PI thinks `&mt` is part of an XML escape code in line

therefore its not recognizing it.